# Show that all solutions of $x'(t) =\small \begin{cases}-x(t)\log(x(t)^2)& x(t)\neq 0 \\0 & x(t)=0\\\end{cases}\quad$ can be written as.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$x'(t) = \begin{cases}-x(t)\log(x(t)^2) ,& x(t)\neq 0 \\\hspace{2,6cm} 0 ,&x(t)=0\\\end{cases}$$

Show that all solutions of $x'(t)$ can be written as

$\\1.\;  x(t)=0 \quad \forall t \in \mathbb{R} \\2.\;x(t)=\exp(c*\exp(-2t))\quad \forall t \in \mathbb{R} \; \text{ and } \; c \in \mathbb{R}\\3.\;x(t)=-\exp(c*\exp(-2t))\quad \forall t \in \mathbb{R} \; \text{ and } \; c \in \mathbb{R} $

Case 1 is clear and case 2 is only solving the ODE. I´m not sure with case 3. Will I get this case because i have to regard $|x| $ in $\log(x^2)$ for solving the ODE?

Comment: Yes. At some point in solving the ODE you have to choose whether to take $x$ to be positive or negative. 2 and 3 are just these two solutions.

Comment: Yeah thx, i did it this way.

Comment: Well it boils down to the fact that $x$ can only be positive, negative, or $0$ and will never change sign. The 0 case is obvious. if $x>0$, then the solution approaches monotonically $x=1$. To see this, look at the sign of the derivative in this range. The same thing happens with $x<0$ at $x=-1$.